# Why SQL OpenXML isn't supported in SQL Azure?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

Why SQL OpenXML isn't supported in SQL Azure? and what are the alternatives we can use with SQL Azure? and finally, would SQL OpenXML be deprecated in upcoming SQL versions?

Comment: Use the SQL Server 2005+ native XML/XQuery methods instead - they're much easier to use and work better. See [Intro to XQuery in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) or [SQL Server 2005 XQuery and XML-DML - Part 1](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050803.htm)

Comment: For anyone here now, this question is out of date. OpenXML is now supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openxml-transact-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must have changed at some point. It appears as of 9.25.2017 openxml is working fine in SQL Azure. I just ran the following example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/examples-using-openxml on a SQL Azure DB and it produced the result shown:

```
DECLARE @DocHandle int  
DECLARE @XmlDocument nvarchar(1000)  
SET @XmlDocument = N'<ROOT>  
<Customer CustomerID="VINET" ContactName="Paul Henriot">  
   <Order OrderID="10248" CustomerID="VINET" EmployeeID="5"   
          OrderDate="1996-07-04T00:00:00">  
      <OrderDetail ProductID="11" Quantity="12"/>  
      <OrderDetail ProductID="42" Quantity="10"/>  
   </Order>  
</Customer>  
<Customer CustomerID="LILAS" ContactName="Carlos Gonzlez">  
   <Order OrderID="10283" CustomerID="LILAS" EmployeeID="3"   
          OrderDate="1996-08-16T00:00:00">  
      <OrderDetail ProductID="72" Quantity="3"/>  
   </Order>  
</Customer>  
</ROOT>'  
-- Create an internal representation of the XML document.  
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @DocHandle OUTPUT, @XmlDocument  
-- Execute a SELECT statement using OPENXML rowset provider.  
SELECT *  
FROM OPENXML (@DocHandle, '/ROOT/Customer',1)  
      WITH (CustomerID  varchar(10),  
            ContactName varchar(20))  
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @DocHandle
```

Output:

```
CustomerID  ContactName
VINET   Paul Henriot
LILAS   Carlos Gonzlez
```

I don't see OPENXML listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-transact-sql-information#transact-sql-syntax-not-supported-in-sql-database

Answer (score 4):

Two alternatives are:

**1) Nodes() and Value() functions**

See [Restrictions of Stored Procedures in SQL Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sajid/archive/2010/04/22/restrictions-of-stored-procedures-in-sql-azure.aspx) and [Value(), Nodes(), and OpenXML()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522645.aspx).

**2) XQuery**

See [Introduction to XQuery in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and [SQL Server 2005 XQuery and XML-DML - Part 1](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/article.php/c19491).

Comment: The link for " Restrictions of Stored Procedures in SQL Azure " is amazing.

Comment: @fernando-correia I'd appreciate you taking a look at my answer below ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/46413643/908677 ) and share your thoughts on whether OPENXML is now supposed in Azure. Thanks!

Comment: @ElijahLofgren - the docs are updated. Full support for OpenXML in Azure SQLDB. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openxml-transact-sql